# android styling news feed for custom array adapter

Tags: android, android-layout

so I usually don't have an issue getting the layout in android but this one is proving to be difficult. I'm sure its a simply fix but I'm just having one of those days when simple stuff doesn't seem to click. I'm creating an app which takes feed from an online source and then displays certain pieces of data. I know I'm getting the data correctly and it showed it on the the list item that I'm making but I want a different layout.

So this is a picture representation of what I'm looking for.[image]

To keep in mind, its a list item xml like one of these [guides:](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

The parts named like "Name", "Details", etc are meant to be their own textviews. They will stay in place and wont be changed. However the ones named "Name data", "Date data", will be changed so they must be separate textviews if possible.

Here is the xml file I'm trying to style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

  <!-- Item Name -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="1"/>      

<!-- Actual Item Name Data -->
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptextdata"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toptext"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="2"/>

 <!-- Date tag -->
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/middletext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toptext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="3"/>

       <!-- Actual Date data -->
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/middletextdata"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toptext"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/middletext"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="4"/>

 <!-- Date tag -->
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/middletext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="5"/>

       <!-- Actual Date data -->
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/middletextdata"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/toptext"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/middletext"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="6"/>

    <!-- open status -->
     <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/desctext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/opentext"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

 <!-- actual open status -->
      <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/opentext"
    android:id="@+id/open2text"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any and all help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What does your layout look like currently? Also, are you getting an error or is it just that the layout that you want to fix?

Comment: just needed a layout rework. no errors or anything like that haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking for something like this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dp"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelName"
    android:text="Name Data" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Date Data" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvDate"
    android:text="Date:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/labelName"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="Details:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/labelDetails"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelDetails"
    android:text="Details Data" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/labelDetails"
    android:text="Live Data" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelLive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/labelDetails"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvDate"
    android:text="Live:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelNews"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/labelDetails"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="News:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNews"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/labelNews"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelNews"
    android:text="News Data" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/labelNews"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you ever have one of those days when you feel like the problem would take some complicated answer and then you're brought back to computer science 1?.... yeah im having one of those days haha. Thanks though! I can't test it at the moment but it looks really solid. I'll comment when I finally test it

Comment: :-) . Its my pleasure. Happy Coding. Bye